# LENGTH Field in IEEE 802.11b

Tags: networking, network-programming, wifi

I am simulating the IEEE802.11b PHY Model. I am building the header of the Packet in the Physical Layer.

As per the Literature

> The PLCP LENGTH field shall be an unsigned 16-bit integer that indicates the number of microseconds to transmit the PPDU.

If I assume the packet size to be 1024Bytes, what should be the value of the Length field(16 bit wide)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The calculation of the `LENGTH` field depends on the number of bytes to send, as well as on the data rate (5.5 or 11 Mbps).  The basic idea of the calculation is:

```
                        Bytes * 8
LENGTH = Time (µs) = ----------------
                     Data rate (Mbps)
```

However, you need to read *Section 18.2.3.5, Long PLCP LENGTH field* in the [802.11b-1999 Standard](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee802/download/802.11b-1999.pdf), pages 15-17.  It has the complete details of how to calculate this value, along with several examples.  It unambiguously explains how to properly round the data, as well as when the *length extension bit* in the `SERVICE` field should be set.

I will not reproduce the text of the section here since it looks like IEEE might be strict about enforcing their copyright.  However, if you don't have the standard already, I suggest you download it now from the link above -- it's free!

If you have any questions about interpreting the standard, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Thanks a Lot for your help. I will have a look. But I got an idea how to set the LENGTH field.

Comment: As far as I can tell, 5.5 and 11 Mbps are the only allowed data rates for 802.11b.  See the table on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11

Comment: Thanks, I was wrong. I had an impression that even 1Mbps and 2Mbps is part of 802.11b Standard.